# Does NServiceBus guarantee that messages will be processed in a particular order?

Tags: nservicebus

Does NServicebus make sure messages are drawn down from a queue in a particular order like FIFO or LIFO?

Thx

Comment: No - Why do you need them to be processed in a particular order?

Comment: For instance if I want to subscribe to a feed of prices I dont want to assume that the last message I get is the most recent price in the market ... that could be a costly mistake!

Comment: Add a timestamp/time period to your updates and use that to make sure that you only store the most resent one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServiceBus doesn't guarantee that messages will be processed in order *(as far as im aware)*. Even if you ran a single thread, you can't guarantee that message 2 doesn't arrive before message 1.

I did a quick google search and also found:

http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/NServiceBus-In-order-message-processing.aspx

Which seems to test the scenario, but came to the conclusion:

> **Conclusion**
>
> NServiceBus doesn’t handle messages
>   in-order. It’s up to the developer to
>   make sure that the relevant messages
>   are handler in the right order. The
>   easiest way to do this is to send
>   messages as batches from the client.

Also if a message fails for some reason, it will be thrown to the back of the queue, and processed out of order from the previous related messages.

Comment: @Andreas Yes thats what I've decided to do was wondering if NSB had a method of doing this

Comment: Having read the linked post, it looks to me that the writer suggests that when the handler is ran under a single thread, NServiceBus DOES not process messages out of order - "Remember our server’s configuration? In our first test the server is using only one thread (NumberOfWorkerThreads) to process all the messages. Because of this, the NServiceBus handles them in order.". Having downloaded the test project for my self, it looks to me that messages of a given type will always be processed in order.

Comment: @BombDefused - While that is true, you can't guarantee the messages got on the queue in order, and you have to decide what to do when a message can't be processed. If a message fails its put back on the queue to retry later and pick up a new message. Not an easy scenario to solve. Probably easier to run them in a saga or something.

Comment: Phil, could you have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463253/does-an-nservicebus-error-mean-that-messages-are-not-processed-in-the-right-orde.  It is similar to this one.  +1.